# Need some guidance on templated lambda predicate

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, closures

I wrote this little snippet:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class A
{
public:

    T fieldoftypet;
    T* tableoft;

    bool (*predicate)(T element);
};

int main()
{
    A<int> obiekt;
    obiekt.fieldoftypet = 1;
    obiekt.tableoft = new int[1];
    obiekt.predicate = [=] (int element) { return element == obiekt.fieldoftypet; };
}
```

I need some guidance on how to make this compile. Compiler error log:

```
$ g++ demotemplates.cpp -o demotemplates.exe
demotemplates.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
demotemplates.cpp:20:80: error: cannot convert ‘main()::<lambda(int)>’ to ‘bool (*)(int)’ in assignment
   20 |  obiekt.predicate = [=] (int element) { return element == obiekt.fieldoftypet; };
      |                                                                                ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class A
{
public:

    T fieldoftypet;
    T* tableoft;

    function<bool(int)> predicate;
};

int main()
{
    A<int> obiekt;
    obiekt.fieldoftypet = 1;
    obiekt.tableoft = new int[1];
    obiekt.predicate = [=] (int element) { return element == obiekt.fieldoftypet; };
    cout << obiekt.predicate(1) << endl;
    cout << obiekt.predicate(2) << endl;
}
```